# toilet slow to flush with bubbles from the jet

Tags: plumbing

There are 3 toilets in the house and the one in the master bath when flushed bubbles come out the jet and the bowel is slow to empty. The tank empties well from the tank. No other issues with the other toilets, sinks or tubs.

any ideas

Comment: Has it always been like this? Can it be that your drain is a bit clogged? Have you tried to use a plunger to see if it would help anything?

Comment: just started a couple of days ago, took the toilet off and its clear. Water goes down the drain and doesn't back up

Comment: The only thing that comes to my mind is that your drain air intake could be somehow blocked. Besides that, I'm no plumber so I can't help you further, sorry.

Comment: also the septic tanked was pumped out about 6 months ago and the house is only 3 years old

Comment: I know I thought that too, but figured it would effect the other toilets on that vent line. Thanks for your help though I am kind of puzzled by it

Answer (score 1):

If the tank water level is correct and you don't detect a restriction/blockage between the tank and bowl, and the drain below the toilet is clear;

the problem could be a restriction/partial blockage in the toilet bowl trap.[image]